# jOOQ - support for JSR310

Tags: java, sql, jooq, jsr310

Does jOOQ provide support for JSR310 in combination with PostgreSQL? In particular, I am trying to use the following classes:

- `java.time.Instant`
- `java.time.LocalDate`
- `java.time.LocalTime`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime`

I am storing in the following data types (as per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html):

- `java.time.Instant`: `timestamp with timezone`
- `java.time.LocalDate`: `date`
- `java.time.LocalTime`: `time without timezone`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime`: `timestamp without timezone`

Are these data types correct?

Does jOOQ support translation between `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` and the four classes above (in both directions)?

Comment: I was unable to find something here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=milestone%3A%22Version+3.7.0%22+jsr and https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=310

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. (I am about to edit my question, the suggested data types are incomplete.)

Comment: OK, I'll wait with the answer, then...

Comment: @LukasEder I finished my edit! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### jOOQ Roadmap

Up until jOOQ 3.6, there was no official support for JSR-310 date time types, because both the jOOQ Open Source Edition and the commercial editions still supported Java 6.

With jOOQ 3.7, this changes as Java 6 is supported only in a specifically built commercial distribution, whereas standard distributions will require Java 8. The relevant issue for this change is [#4338](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4338).

Another change involves a flag `<javaTimeTypes/>` to tell the source code generator to generate JSR-310 types rather than `java.sql.Date` and similar types. By default, this flag is set to false, so you will need to set it to true until issue [#5714](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5714) is resolved.

#### Using JSR-310 types with jOOQ 3.6 or less

In the meantime, you can bind the desired types yourself and let the code generator use your custom `Converter` or `Binding`. See the relevant sections in the manual:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

#### The correct mapping

The [JDBC 4.2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html) defines which JSR-310 data types should be mapped to which JDBC data types (which coincide with PostgreSQL's understanding of the same). In particular, the JDBC spec lists:

- Added support to map `java.time.LocalDate` to JDBC `DATE`.
- Added support to map `java.time.LocalTime` to JDBC `TIME`
- Added support to map `java.time.LocalDateTime` to JDBC `TIMESTAMP`.
- Added support to map `java.time.OffsetTime` to JDBC `TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE`.
- Added support to map `java.time.OffsetDateTime` to JDBC `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`.

JDBC's understanding does not seem entirely correct, though, as few databases really store the timezone information in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type (e.g. Oracle does), see also this DBA/StackExchange answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59021/2512. Since the time zone is not stored, your approach of mapping `java.time.Instant` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is better, because the SQL type is really just a UTC timestamp.

Having said so, `OffsetDateTime` can still be mapped to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, but you will not know what time zone was used when the timestamp was stored in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information. The links are also very useful! I will try to implement my own converters. If you need help with the development, feel free to leave me a note. I have some spare time at the end of next month.

Comment: @SophiaAceves: Thanks for the offer. We're already halfway through the implementation. :) But perhaps there are other things you might like to do. How can I reach you?

Answer (score 6):

JSR-310 support is now available in jOOQ 3.9.0 to configure in code:

```
new Configuration()
     .withGenerator(new Generator()
          .withGenerate(new Generate()
              .withJavaTimeTypes(true)));
```

The same structure would apply in the xml config (Configuration - Generator - Generate - javaTimeTypes)

Keep an eye on https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5714 to see when this is enabled by default.